# When did Athenian archers pepper Spartan hoplites with arrows for days on an island?

Tags: war, ancient-greece, battle, athens, sparta

The heading is basically all I remember from school. The hoplites lacked [mobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_tactics) and were thus harassed for day by the lightly armored Athenian archers. Athenian victory.

Comment: See [Battle of Sphacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sphacteria).

Comment: @LarsBosteen well ... yeah ... this answers the question. Perhaps the question should be removed as trivial or expanded to e.g. query also about the tactics of the battle?

Comment: Bettany Hughes [talked about it](https://youtu.be/99WJDLpgo3U?t=2408)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly remembering of the history of the garrison of [Sphacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sphacteria) island.

Some things to adjust from the description you made:

- Athenians did not only use archers, but javeliniers as well
- Spartans were isolated by the water, in the island